# Source multiple sql files with blank in name

Tags: bash, mysql, cat

I'm actually blocking on a stupid thing ... yet i can't get it throught.

We've got a git repository on which we have our php files and our sql patch.
Every time i update my repo, i have to check if any sql patch has to be played.
To avoid searching wich one is to play, i've made a small script that give me every sql file taht my last git pull gave me:

```
find $MY_DIR/scripts/sandbox/migrations -type f -newermt $(date +'%Y-%m-%d') ! -newermt $(date +'%Y-%m-%d' --date="tomorrow") -not -path "$MY_DIR/scripts/sandbox/migrations/generated/*"
```

This gives me and output that looks like this

```
/home/carpette/www/myFolder/scripts/sandbox/migrations/done/2017.12.14 - script1.sql
/home/carpette/www/myFolder/scripts/sandbox/migrations/done/2017.09.28 - script2.sql
/home/carpette/www/myFolder/scripts/sandbox/migrations/done/2017.12.15 - script3.sql
/home/carpette/www/myFolder/scripts/sandbox/migrations/done/2017.12.12 - script4.sql
```

Now, i'm trying to source those files automaticaly in mysql.
I've tried doing something like this:

`mysql myDataBase < $(./myStript.sh)`

But i get an error message with `ambiguous redirection`.

So i tried:

`cat $(./myScript.sh) | mysql myDataBase`

But now, the space contained in my filename path is blocking, and mysql said "no existing file" because it takes only `/home/carpette/www/myFolder/scripts/sandbox/migrations/done/2017.09.28` as filename path.

I guess i have to escape the blanks, but i'm not finding any elegant solution that works.

Update: I want to keep myScript.sh independant, so that i can steel use it in other things.

Comment: I think you would be better off executing the myStript.sh script and then take each line as a file path and pass it to mysql with "mysql myDataBase < $RETURNEDLINE"

Comment: In fact, that is litteraly what i'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./myStript.sh | while read line
do 
    mysql myDataBase < "$line"
done
```

Run the script and take the output line by line, passing the result as a file path to mysql for it to read in and process. Add quotes to the $line variable (file path) to take account of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`find $MY_DIR/scripts/sandbox/migrations -type f \
-newermt $(date +'%Y-%m-%d') ! \
-newermt $(date +'%Y-%m-%d' --date="tomorrow") \
-not -path "$MY_DIR/scripts/sandbox/migrations/generated/*" \
-exec msqlclient MyDatabase -u $USER -h $HOST -p < "{}" \;`

Replace $USER and $HOST as appropriate

Comment: I might have specified that i want to keep both treatment independants. I update my question